# How to change image without refreshing the page

Tags: c#, jquery, html, jquery-ui, updatepanel

I have a website where the user can select different cards.  I need a way where when a new card is selected then the page does not refresh.  When I click the back button now it just goes back to previous selections. I need it to go back to the previous page.  Here is the code for the image change

```
   <div class="imgCard" style="padding-right: 50px">
       <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                  <fieldset style="border-width: 150px; border-style: none">
                        <asp:Image ID="imgCardChoice1" runat="server" />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <a id="openChange1" href="#" style="color: Red">Change Card</a>
                   </fieldset>
             </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

When the user clicks on "Change Card" then a jquery modal box opens and allows them to change the card.  Thank you for any help/advice.  If needed the code behind to select a new card is in C#.

Comment: can you not set the `PostBack` for that page to `#` since you are using an `UpdatePanel`?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more, it sounds like you need to use AJAX to do that.  If you are already using jQuery, check out jQuery.load().  You can make an AJAX request to a url on your site that will only return the image information and load that into the element you specify.

Here is a link to the docs:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some javascript function.
create a div where you want to put your image.
then give him an ID, on javascript function call the div id and change the src to the image that you want to put.
on your link or wathever you have to change the image, call the onclick function and use the javascript function.
On my website i have 2 images, that onmouseover change an image in other div completely different.
see it on:http://roundhillevents.com
and pass the cursor on the facebook and on the youtube logo's.
If nothing appears, let stay the cursor over that a little while.
PS: Only works with forefox and don't know why.